# What does みてみた mean here?

Tags: translation

```
どう、教えたつり場には行ってみてみたー？
```

Is it use to emphasize てみる?

Comment: I think this is almost certainly a mere typo for "行ってみたー?". But there is maybe a 3% chance that it was "行って, 見てみた (go and try seeing it)", and there is maybe a 1% chance that it was an intentional wordplay...

Comment: I have another example - ちょっくら森の外に出てみてみー

Comment: "森の外に出てみてみ" could mean "try and go outside the forest", Or "try and see what's beyond the edge of the forest."  In language translation there are no true absolutes, just read the context.

Comment: Is this a character in fiction who says a lot of things like this?

Comment: Yes, it's a character from video game.

Comment: ^ So.. this is the character's "unique" way of speaking. They double the subsidiary verb みる: 「行ってみた？」→「行ってみてみた？」、「出てみー」→「出てみてみー」 ... これってちょっとかわいく聞こえますよね。もしかして女の子のキャラですかね？

Answer (score 3):

みてみる is a set expression fairly equivalent in meaning to the colloquial English: ‘look and see’ or 'check out'.

The first みる denotes basic physical observation with the eyes. The second indicates an evaluation of what was seen.

Take the simple expression 見たいです. This means ‘I want to see (it).
Contrast this with the expression 見てみたいです. This would be closer to ‘I want to check it out’ (physically observe and evaluate it).

> どう、教えたつり場には行ってみてみたー？
>
> How is it, did you go and check out the fishing spot that I told you about?

行きたいです　I want to go
行ってみたいです I want to go (and check it out)

Just as the English word ‘see’ has different definitions, (to perceive to the eye; to examine or watch), so does みる. Look can be considered in some cases a synonym for see, but they both have different separate meanings. Hence, the 'look and see' expression makes sense and is not redundant.

Answer (score 0):

> 行ってみてみた

At first, I thought it was a typo as is written in naruto's comment, but I found a lot of same examples as follows on the Internet:

- 本屋に**行ってみてみた**んですが、高校参考書ほど充実はしていないんですね。
- 先日アンチャーテッドエルドラドの秘宝を買おうと、店に**行ってみてみた**のですが、トロフィー機能がついてなかった？です。
- 公式ホームページに**行ってみてみた**んだけど、ニケが13歳でククリが12歳って本当っすか・・・・。
- 日本で調べたり、海外投資セミナーで話を聞いて頭の中にイメージしていたものと現地に**行ってみてみた**ものではかなり雰囲気が違います。
- あの撮影の後、二度ほど**行ってみてみた**のだけどなんか響くものが無くてね もっと勉強しなおしかなさて大阪着いたので肉を食べてくるよ。
- 友達にも家族にも相談も出来ず、新宿にも**行ってみてみた**。
- 一体これはどのような建物なのか、最終日そばまで**行ってみてみた**のですが？

In Japanese there are expressions "行って**みる**" and "見て**みる**" for "行く" and "見る" respectively.

"みる" in the above expressions is defined in jisho.org [here](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%BF%E3%82%8B) as:

> 5. to try; to try out; to test
>      ​Usually written using kana alone, usu. after a conative verb as 〜てみる
>      もう一度{いちど}着｛き｝てみていいですか。 *May I put it on again?*

I think that "行ってみてみる" has a nuance that "行ってみる" and "見てみる" are said all together.

Although "行ってみてみる" certainly feels somewhat weird at the first time, there is a certain expression that "行ってみてみ" that is close to "行ってみてみる". Furthermore, their polite expressions "行ってみてご覧（なさい） *Try to go and see, please.*" or "行ってみてきてご覧（なさい）" are relatively common expressions.

As another interpretation of "行ってみてみる", "行ってみる" is originally constructed of "行く + みる", but as it is used too commonly as if one word, we casually attach "みる" as the definition in the above dictionary and try to emphasize the meaning of "行ってみる".